# Can't see my service installer when trying to Install a Windows Service

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, service, windows-services, service-installer

I wrote a Windows Service in c# (VS2008) and now trying to install it (My project's name is MyProject).
I am following the steps on the article http://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/zt39148a(v=VS.90).aspx

and when I get to the highlighted step:
[image]

I cannot see "MyNewService". I can only see "MyProject.project"
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will encounter problems installing Windows Service with [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) (mentioned in the question)

I used http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816169 and it worked well!

Hope it will help you too!

Answer (score 0):

Look like the The "MyNewService" in the above example is their sample project.  Just choose your project name there and then build your project. You should be good to go

Note: for instructions on how to actually install the service on your target machine see here

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/d8f300e3-6c09-424f-829e-c5fda34c1bc7

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! their "MyNewService" is the serviceInstaller, and I just don't see the serviceInstaller in the list at all. I can only see <my project name>.project... I tried to pick that one, just to see if it will work, but then on the next steps I had to add a new project of the type Setup and Deployment Projects and choose my installer, and couldn't see it there too